cannot connect laravel with mysql inside a docker container
I have laravel 11 application and it works fine. I want the application to run inside docker and I have the following docker file set up for the laravel app:
FROM php:8.3-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

WORKDIR /var/www

COPY . /var/www/

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php \
    && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN composer install

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["php", "artisan", "serve", "--host=127.0.0.1", "--port=8000"]

and here is my .env file for laravel.
APP_NAME="News"
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:54Cuy//nhKFvtc+ir8SY6VinO6Av+qIdMSj9R9YSm8g=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC
APP_URL=http://localhost

APP_LOCALE=en
APP_FALLBACK_LOCALE=en
APP_FAKER_LOCALE=en_US

APP_MAINTENANCE_DRIVER=file
# APP_MAINTENANCE_STORE=database

BCRYPT_ROUNDS=12

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_STACK=single
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=dbnews
DB_USERNAME=dbuser
DB_PASSWORD=dbpasss

SESSION_DRIVER=database
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_ENCRYPT=false
SESSION_PATH=/
SESSION_DOMAIN=null

SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost,127.0.0.1

BROADCAST_CONNECTION=log
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database

CACHE_STORE=database
CACHE_PREFIX=

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_CLIENT=phpredis
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.domain.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=user@domain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD='&6gT5%$'
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=info@domain.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

VITE_APP_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

I am using docker compose so here is the docker-compose.yml file:
services:
  laravel:
    build:
      context: ./back
    volumes:
      - ./back:/var/www
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dbnews
      MYSQL_USER: dbuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: dbpass
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql

  nuxt:
    build:
      context: ./front
    volumes:
      - ./front:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - laravel

volumes:
  db_data:

docker compose up --build produces the following output:
db_1       | 2024-09-18 13:14:45+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.39-1.el9 started.
db_1       | 2024-09-18 13:14:45+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
db_1       | 2024-09-18 13:14:45+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.39-1.el9 started.
db_1       | '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
db_1       | 2024-09-18T13:14:45.813462Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
db_1       | 2024-09-18T13:14:45.815269Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.39) starting as process 1
db_1       | 2024-09-18T13:14:45.821078Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
laravel_1  | 
laravel_1  |    INFO  Server running on [http://127.0.0.1:8000].  
laravel_1  | 
laravel_1  |   Press Ctrl+C to stop the server
laravel_1  | 
db_1       | 2024-09-18T13:14:46.215960Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
db_1       | 2024-09-18T13:14:46.355592Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
nuxt_1     | 
nuxt_1     | > nuxt-app@ dev /app
nuxt_1     | > nuxt dev
nuxt_1     | 
db_1       | 2024-09-18T13:14:46.377436Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
db_1       | 2024-09-18T13:14:46.415536Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
db_1       | 2024-09-18T13:14:46.415570Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
db_1       | 2024-09-18T13:14:46.420131Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
db_1       | 2024-09-18T13:14:46.449135Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
db_1       | 2024-09-18T13:14:46.449332Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.39'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
nuxt_1     | Nuxt 3.13.1
nuxt_1     | 
nuxt_1     |  WARN  The CJS build of Vite's Node API is deprecated. See https://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#vite-cjs-node-api-deprecated for more details.
nuxt_1     | 
nuxt_1     | 
nuxt_1     |   ➜ Local:    http://localhost:3000/
nuxt_1     |   ➜ Network:  use --host to expose
nuxt_1     | 
nuxt_1     | 
nuxt_1     |  WARN  The CJS build of Vite's Node API is deprecated. See https://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#vite-cjs-node-api-deprecated for more details.
nuxt_1     | 
nuxt_1     |   ➜ DevTools: press Shift + Alt + D in the browser (v1.4.2)
nuxt_1     | 
nuxt_1     | ✔ Vite client built in 47ms
nuxt_1     | ✔ Vite server built in 1305ms
nuxt_1     | [nitro] ✔ Nuxt Nitro server built in 585 ms
nuxt_1     | ℹ Vite client warmed up in 0ms
nuxt_1     | ℹ Vite server warmed up in 2306ms


and I can access the front nuxt application fine but the cannot access localhost:8000 at all. When I could connect to the laravel app I got the following error in the browser:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: Name or service not known (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from sessions where id = b5JVyzFscjEITCRRj7Hud0lxhyN9hyYX4pK29hyK limit 1) 

but now I cannot connect at all so a new issue.
If I then run the same docker compose up --build command again I get the following error:
ERROR: for laravel  'ContainerConfig'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 81, in main
    command_func()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 203, in perform_command
    handler(command, command_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/metrics/decorator.py", line 18, in wrapper
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 1186, in up
    to_attach = up(False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 1166, in up
    return self.project.up(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/project.py", line 697, in up
    results, errors = parallel.parallel_execute(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/parallel.py", line 108, in parallel_execute
    raise error_to_reraise
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/parallel.py", line 206, in producer
    result = func(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/project.py", line 679, in do
    return service.execute_convergence_plan(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 579, in execute_convergence_plan
    return self._execute_convergence_recreate(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 499, in _execute_convergence_recreate
    containers, errors = parallel_execute(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/parallel.py", line 108, in parallel_execute
    raise error_to_reraise
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/parallel.py", line 206, in producer
    result = func(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 494, in recreate
    return self.recreate_container(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 612, in recreate_container
    new_container = self.create_container(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 330, in create_container
    container_options = self._get_container_create_options(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 921, in _get_container_create_options
    container_options, override_options = self._build_container_volume_options(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 960, in _build_container_volume_options
    binds, affinity = merge_volume_bindings(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 1548, in merge_volume_bindings
    old_volumes, old_mounts = get_container_data_volumes(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 1579, in get_container_data_volumes
    container.image_config['ContainerConfig'].get('Volumes') or {}
KeyError: 'ContainerConfig'

I upgraded to the latest docker desktop so not really sure what to do next. If I delete the containers and start again I do not get the last set of errors.
Anybody can help me how to make this work please?

You have several things going on here.  The last error block is the result of trying to use an old version of Compose against a new version of the Docker Engine that's made an API change.  You can't reach your services because they're listening on 127.0.0.1; they generally need to listen on 0.0.0.0 or else they'll be unreachable from outside their own container.  When your backend connects to the database it needs to use the Compose service name db as the host name.  The various mentions of localhost could also be problematic, since that name usually refers to the current container only.

Use your mysql containr's name for DB_HOST.
DB_HOST=db

In the .env file? I tried it doesn't work. Gives the following error now:SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: Temporary failure in name resolution (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from sessions where id = b5JVyzFscjEITCRRj7Hud0lxhyN9hyYX4pK29hyK limit 1)
